# How to decode the wrong encoded "b'\\xc3\\xb1'" on Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

How can I output the incoming name data as a regular string? My code is here.

```
playerName = u''.join((name)).encode('utf-8').strip()
```

the output of this line

```
I\xc3\xb1aki Williams
```

must be `Iñaki Williams`

Comment: `b'I\xc3\xb1aki Williams'.decode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: Doesn't `''.join((name)).strip()` work?

Comment: ".encode('utf-8')" means that you are converting the string to a `bytes` object, which is *not a string*. This object *can not represent* the symbol `ñ`. You should not do this step, unless you have a much more specific purpose in mind (in which case you need to ask a much more detailed question to match, and you should also research what you are doing first). Also, the code you show does not actually product that output, or *any* output at all.

Comment: @Swier cool, this worked me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code prints "Iñaki Williams"

```
name = "I\xc3\xb1aki Williams"
name = name.encode('latin')
name = name.decode()
print(name)
```